# Запрограммированные действия на стороннем сайте

Tags: javascript

Есть к примеру код:

```
while(true) {
    if (document.getElementById('card-title1').innerText === 'Привет') {
        document.getElementById('card1-main').click();
    }
    else {
        window.location.reload();
    }
}
```

И мне нужно запустить его на стороннем сайте. Это можно сделать через "инструменты разработчика", но при перезагрузке страницы, код работать перестанет. Желательно чтобы этот код был на JS, но не принципиально.

Comment: Поставьте какое-нибудь расширение для юзерскриптов и создайте юзерскрипт, например?

Comment: Через расширение Tampermonkey можно добавлять свои скрипты на сайты. Я так у одного сайта вернул функционал выделение и копирования текста - у них скрипт устанавливал определенный класс, а мой скрипт дожидался выполнения того и убирал за ним :D